# UITextView text bleeding effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My iPhone project requires that an image (probably in an `UIImageView`) be  placed somewhere on a `UITextView` and it should not overlap the text (, instead the text should appear around the image accommodating it). If the image is moved the text should re-adjust so that it doesn't get cut and reappear around the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is called wrapping.

You'll probably need to use Core Text. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

Previous related questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313156/test-wrapping-around-image-in-ios

[How Can I Draw Image with Text Wrapping on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284516/how-can-i-draw-image-with-text-wrapping-on-ios)