# How to use CoreText to draw text around images

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, core-text

I'm trying to subclass `UIView` to build a control that will use `CoreText` to draw text around some images, where the location of the images will be determined by tags in the text I'm drawing.

For example, I'd get a string like this:

```
     "Here is some text <img src="img1.png" width="20" height="20"> and here is the rest of the text."
```

Basically, I want to replace everything between the `<>` with the `20x20` image it references, and draw all the text before the tag in front of it and all the text after the tag after the image.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284516/how-can-i-draw-image-with-text-wrapping-on-ios)

Comment: That post helped a little bit, but he just hardcoded a rect for the text to flow around and I need to do it dynamically by finding tags in the string and that's the part I can't figure out.