# Format UILabel and UIImages with CoreText

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uiimage, core-text

i don't worked enougth with core text, but as i thought it's only possible way to do this, but who knows.
So i have a server, that sends me information:

```
NSString *text = @"hello, today is best day";
NSArray *images; // array of url's from server to images (http://80.89.ru/123.png ....) 
// I don't know how many url's there will be
```

I have a window, in this window i need to correctly draw UILabel with that string and all images, that i get from server with this text.
So i configured UILabel in InterfaceBuilder and config my label with images into ViewController

```
@interface ViewC()
{
   UILabel *longStringFromServer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int y = 20; int x = 20;
    for (NSString *url in images)
    {
        UIImageView *view = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame....];
        y += 50; 
        // load image by url into UIImageView
    }
    longStringFromServer = text;
}
```

---

What I have:

### [image: enter code here]

What I need:

### [image]

How do i can reach that result on second picture ?

Comment: I can't look now but you can create exclusion regions when rendering with core text. This will wrap the text around the region. Add the image frames as exclusion regions.

Comment: Does this regions can create dynamically in case of images number ? Can you give me example of how to do this with NSString and UILabel ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Draw Image with Text Wrapping on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284516/how-can-i-draw-image-with-text-wrapping-on-ios)

Comment: Also a great tutorial on doing this: http://robnapier.net/wrapping-text-around-shape-with-coretext

Comment: Use TextKit and the exclusionPaths for the NSTextContainer might help you in this case.